# Remove chapter number from memoir class ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, memoir, chapters

Is there a way to remove the chapter numbers from a `memoir` class table of contents? I would like to have the name of the chapter followed by the page number on which it occurs. It would be nice to have dot leaders as well. The `memoir` manual says:

> In the default ToC typesetting only the more minor entries have dotted leader lines between the sectioning title and the page number. The class provides for general leaders for all entries. The 'dot' in a leader is given by the value of `\cftdot`. Its default definition is `\newcommand{\cftdot}{.}` which gives the default dotted leader. By changing `\cftdot` you can use symbols other than a period in the leader. For example
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\cftdot}{\ensuremath{\ast}}
> ```
>
> will result in a dotted leader using asterisks as the symbol.

Putting the command `\cftdot` in the preamble does nothing; putting it before `\tableofcontents` does nothing; putting it after `\tableofcontents` does nothing.

Comment: What about the chapter numbers on the actual chapter page?

Comment: They can stay. (added text to meet requirement that "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should update two macros in order to achieve your desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% Gobble chapter number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapter dots in ToC
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

`\chapternumberline` formats the number associated with the `\chapter` entry in the ToC, while `\cftchapterdotsep` (default is `\cftnodots`) should default to `\cftdotsep`.